# Creating a promise for web worker's onmessage event with nth number of REST calls

Tags: javascript, rest, recursion, promise, web-worker

I am using web workers to fetch information of websites including their subsites(nth number) recursively. When all of the calls are done I want to fire off a function that would format the data it receives (allSites array). So I thought it would be a great idea to use a Promise.all with an object that has all my resolved promises.

The problem is that it doesn't wait for all the resolved promises because it's waiting to hear messages posted from the worker. I can't define a length because it could be any number of websites + subsites.

**Bonus:** I have an object with resolved promises. Can I call a certain resolve like this?

```
keyName[index]()
```

It says it's not a function but shouldn't I be able to call it like that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function getTreeData(cb) {
  let allSites = [];
  let baseUrl = "https://www.somewebsite.com/"
  let resolver = {};
  let rejecter = {};
  let workerUrl =
    "https://www.somewebsite.com/siteassets/worker.js";
  let myWorker = new Worker(workerUrl);

  function firstIteration() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolver[baseUrl] = resolve;
      rejecter[baseUrl] = reject;
      myWorker.postMessage({
        requestDigest: document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
        qs1: "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
        qs2:
          "/_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings",
        url: baseUrl,
      });
    });
  }
  firstIteration();

  //spawn a worker
  myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
    allSites = allSites.concat([
      { pathname: e.data.url, groups: e.data.permissions },
    ]);

    e.data.sites.forEach(function (props) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myWorker.postMessage({
          requestDigest: document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
          qs1: "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
          qs2:
            "/_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings",
          url: "www.somewebsite.com" + props.url,
        });
        resolver[props.url] = resolve;
        rejecter[props.url] = reject;
      });
    });
    resolver[e.data.url](); //it says that it is not a function
  };

  myWorker.onerror = function (e) {
    rejecter[e.data.url]();
  };
  
  //After my first inital promises resovles resolve the rest (checks object of resolves)
  resolver[baseUrl]().then(() => {
    Promise.all(Object.values(resolver)).then(() => {
      reduceData(cb, allSites);
    });
  });
}
```

Though it is working properly here's the code for the web worker. (worker.js)

```
function formatSites(props) {
  return {
    url: "www.someSite.com",
  };
}

function formatSitesInfo(props) {
  //get all info of the site or subsite
  var accessArr = props.RoleDefinitionBindings.results
    .reduce(function (r, a) {
      return r.concat([a.Name]);
    }, [])
    .sort()
    .join(", ");
  return {
    access: accessArr,
    isGroup: props.Member.hasOwnProperty("AllowRequestToJoinLeave")
      ? true
      : false,
    name: props.Member.Title,
    members: (props.Member.Users?.results || []).map(function (member) {
      return {
        access: accessArr,
        email: member.Email,
        groupName: props.Member.Title,
        id: member.Id,
        isAdmin: member.IsSiteAdmin,
        title: member.Title,
      };
    }),
  };
}

function _getRequest(props) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(props.url + props.qs, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": props.requestDigest,
      },
    })
      .then(function (resp) {
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  });
}

self.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
  if (!e.data.data) {
    var promise1 = _getRequest(Object.assign(e.data, { qs: e.data.qs1 }));
    var promise2 = _getRequest(Object.assign(e.data, { qs: e.data.qs2 }));

    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function ([data1, data2]) {
      self.postMessage({
        info: data2.d.results.map(formatSitesInfo),
        sites: data1.d.results.map(formatSites),
        url: e.data.url,
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: A couple of errors here,  `Promise.all` returns a promise, your not doing anything with this promise, so it's a NULL OP.  Second `fetch` returns a promise, but your don't return it in your `_getRequest`, and using a Promise constructor here is an anti-pattern anyway.

Comment: Yes, it should return a promise. After the first call is made the Promise.all() would go through the values of the resolver obj. The resolver obj looks like this resolver = { site1: f(), site2; f()} the values equals resolve. So finding that all values are0 "resolve" it should go the next function; the thenable which is my formatter func

Comment: For the fetch promise: Since it is in a promise.all it would either show resolve or reject. I don't have a catch (bad practice) but you should be able to write it that way.

Comment: Reading up right now about the constructor antipattern

Comment: As far as I can tell, you never set `resolver[e.data.url]` to anything.  You set `resolver[e.data.sites[i].url]` for some integers `i`, and you set `resolver[baseUrl]`  Do you know that `e.data.url` is one of those values?

Comment: @ScottSauyet e.data.url is the url that comes back from the web worker postmessage (worker.js) The resolver obj looks like this: 
resolver: {
https://www.somewebsite.com: ƒ (),
/sites/itef/MD: ƒ (),
/sites/itef/MD/M1: ƒ (),
/sites/itef/MD/M2: ƒ (),
/sites/itef/MD/M2/M21: ƒ (),
/sites/itef/MD/M3: ƒ (),
...
}

Comment: But when do you assign that as a property of `resolver`?  You try to call it, and note an issue with the comment *`//it says that it is not a function`*, but I don't see where you set that value.

Comment: resolver is an object. So there a few ways you can assign new key value pairs to an object. There is dot notation, bracket notation, and Object.assign. resolver[e.data.url] is bracket notation. the value e.data.url is from the web worker. Look at teh bottom of worker.js for the postmessage.

Comment: I think I was setting the value as resolver[e.data.url](); but it needed to be resolver[e.data.url]; I don't get that error anymore but I still no work though

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused.  But I see you setting the `resolver`'s property values of `props.url`, but passing `"https://intelshare.intelink.gov" + props.url` to the worker, and I'm not following.  Any chance you can set up a Fiddle or some such to show the issues?

Comment: Ahh I forgot to exclude that... "https://intelshare.intelink.gov is "https://www.somewebsite.com/"The props.url is the path element referring to different sites and subsites... updated my post! good find

Comment: Later today or so I can replicate this issue. So you guys can better understand where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a timer to would be reset if there's a another call to the worker(another subsite was found to have childern). If the timer stops that means that we have reached the end of childern for the sites. It then goes to the next function. There will be a dash of latency, but it's something I can live with.